# Detecting when a device has changed physical ethernet port

Tags: c#, networking, device

My code is running on a server with multiple Ethernet ports which are physically wired to specific physical locations. Devices with known IPs are plugged in the other ends. I want to be able to detect if a device has changed place (in order to warn/scold the user). I.e, the difference between this:

```
Port X (192.168.33.1) ------------------ Device A (192.168.33.12)
Port Y (192.168.33.2) ------------------ Device B (192.168.33.13)
```

and this:

```
Port X (192.168.33.1) ------------------ Device B (192.168.33.13)
Port Y (192.168.33.2) ------------------ Device A (192.168.33.12)
```

I've considered putting the devices/ports on different subnets, but I would *prefer* to be able to say "you need to move device C to position N", rather than "I can't see anything!".

*Disclaimer: I am not a networking expert*

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you're actually talking to these devices in some way, shape or form, and sooner or later you'll have a [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socket) object (either one you directly created or one that you can obtain from a higher level object such as [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcpclient)'s `Client` property.

Once you've actually used the socket, you'll be able to query the [`LocalEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socket.localendpoint) property and determine which local IP address you actually used to talk to the remote system:

> The `LocalEndPoint` property is usually set after you make a call to the `Bind` method. If you allow the system to assign your socket's local IP address and port number, the `LocalEndPoint` property will be set after the first I/O operation. For connection-oriented protocols, the first I/O operation would be a call to the `Connect` or `Accept` method. For connectionless protocols, the first I/O operation would be any of the send or receive calls.

Comment: Thanks, the situation is slightly more complicated than I described, but I'm going to see if I can try this out.